# Choir needs a new space to house sheet music library. Ideas?

Tags: sheet-music, choir, storage

Our choir used to have storage space for our sizable music library within the college with which we are affiliated. Recently and without notice, the space was reclaimed by the college and we were forced to remove our library. We were not provided an alternative space by the college. I don't know the exact dimensions of the the space our library  previously inhabited, but let's say it was the size of a double large conference room. This allowed space for our librarians to work in addition to storing the music. So, we don't require space quite that large, necessarily, but we'll need room to move about to access selecting pieces for concerts; i.e., we cannot have the music permanently stacked several boxes deep. We are hesitant to rent space in public storage for fear the music may be damaged by weather, flooding or sprinklers. Moreover, we must adhere to a budget and did not have to pay for storage prior to this upheaval. Any ideas for a low-cost, safe storage space with room to work picking and sorting? Many thanks.

Comment: Wow, sorry. Quick thought - rent a climate controlled place to buy some time. It costs money and labor (two moves), but should give you time to figure out a long term soluton.

Comment: Yeah, this is a bummer of a situation! I don't have an answer, I just wanted to say: don't forget the digital (ie, scanned) option. It's not ideal, but it can work in a pinch.

Comment: Your choir required *two conference rooms' space* just to store all music they own? That would be millions of pages, which seems unlikely to me. You should definitely find out more exactly what the requirements are, otherwise we can't give you very useful advice.

Comment: Kilian, thanks for responding. The previous, large space was not just to store the music, but also provided space for our librarians to work. We do actually have an enormous collection of music though, accumulated over a few decades for a choir of about 150 people. So, we don't necessarily need space quite that large, but we would need to store the music in such a way that picking would be accessible without having to haul stacks of boxes about so much. I will edit my post to be more specific. Thanks.